# creating a web application with Microsoft AD SAML

Tags: saml-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I have implemented OAUTH 2.0 authentication with MSAL libraries as below.
`clientApplication.getAuthorizationRequestUrl(parameters).toString();` to invoke authorization endpoint and
`clientApplication.acquireToken(authorizationCodeParameters)` to aquire token from authorization code.

Now I have to implement the same flow for SAML V2.0 protocol too and need some help from the Microsoft team in finding related libraries with which I can invoke /saml2/ endpoint and fetch saml assertions.

I'm using Spring boot 2.2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no official Microsoft SAML libraries.

There is a [list](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) of client-side libraries.

Comment: Thanks.
Later, I explored coveooss library,  which has clients and it is the easiest one to invoke ADFS to fetch SAML assertions. Here is the link for https://github.com/coveooss/saml-client

Comment: Thanks. I added it to the list.